# TinyMCE json image_list and title attribute to image

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE gem in rails and I have following custom init for editor:

```
tinymce.init({
              .... some settings
              plugins: "image, link, table, lists, preview",
              image_list: <%= cms_images_json %>,
              image_title: true
            });
```

cms_images_json is as following:

```
[{\"alt\":\"hoho\",\"title\":\"hoho\",\"value\":\"https://marketing.s3.amazonaws.com/media/cms_images/2/medium_73321705_2348489878614174_2709988140298272768_n.jpg\"},
{\"alt\":\"img2\",\"title\":\"img2\",\"value\":\"https://marketing.s3.amazonaws.com/media/cms_images/3/medium_Bilendo_Blog_-_ebook.jpg\"},
{\"alt\":\"more title req\",\"title\":\"more title req\",\"value\":\"https://marketing.s3.amazonaws.com/media/cms_images/4/medium_Lord-Shiva-Nilkanth-Mahadev.jpg\"}]
```

I want to populate title field in the following form, and currently i have the alt field populated with title from my json. Is there a way to achieve it?

[image]